# Installing Symfony Symfony 3.2.6 with PHP7 requirements

Tags: php, symfony

I have installed Symfony 3.2.6 following below instructions:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#creating-symfony-applications-with-composer (I am working on windows os)

After installing I run /config.php and thats what i get:

> 1. intl ICU version installed on your system is outdated (57.1) and does not match the ICU data bundled with Symfony (58.2) To get the
>      latest internationalization data upgrade the ICU system package and
>      the intl PHP extension.
> 2. a PHP accelerator should be installed Install and/or enable a PHP accelerator (highly recommended).

I am kinda new to symfony (also not extremely experienced in php configuration). I looked around a bit and found intl extension on https://pecl.php.net/package/intl but there is only versions for php 5.3 - 5.5 (whats strange I have installed last xampp with php7 on board and found there php_intl.dll but is supports ICU 57.1 v not recomended 58.2).
About the accelerator thing (whatever it should be- not clearly explained) I found in documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/requirements.html#optional that I need

> APC 3.0.17+ (or another opcode cache needs to be installed).

A have also checked it on pecl site, but fint APC only for 5.4 php. 
However i found also APCu and APCu bc (backwards compatibility) for php 7. After instaling both mentioned extensions symfony still claims, that accelerator is not installed.

My question is how can i manage those two recomendations on php 7 using xampp on windows?

**EDIT**

Second problem solved. As @zerkms mentioned, i just added two lines in php.ini:

```
zend_extension=C:\xampp\php\ext\php_opcache.dll
opcache.enable=1
```

Now the only problem is with intl anc ICU extensions

Comment: You don't need to install anything for php7, simply check `opcache.enable` in phpinfo (and it's odd it is not enabled for you by default)

Comment: I turned it opcache.enabled=1, but symfony still doesn't accept that

Comment: Have you confirmed it has changed? PS: it's `enable` without `d`

Comment: Yes, confirmed and restarted apache. PS. Ofcourse enable (misclicked "d")

Comment: So, if it is enabled there is no chance symfony can still complain about it.

Comment: I had to add zend_extension=C:\xampp\php\ext\php_opcache.dll (path to extension)

Comment: For opcache all I did was add: zend_extension=php_opcache.dll